# Browse server files in ZK

Tags: zk

We are building a web application within ZK framework and we need the functionality of browsing server-side files. I do not know any component to do that so please, do you know if there exists such component or any way to do it?

Thank yoy very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Zk-filebrowser](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/56355/zk-filebrowser-released/)?

If you want to do your own, then you need to [create a tree model](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Model/Tree_Model) which returns entries from the server's file system.

Comment: Thank you!, I can also create my own ViewModel which return such entries.